# How to make Proton work correctly on Debian?

Tags: steam, linux, directx-11

Some months ago I tried using Ubuntu (18.04) as my gaming setup. There I used Steam and its compatibility layer Proton. It worked just fine.

Now, I am using Debian (12), because my gaming PCs sata controller has given up. I use the same graphics card (Nvidia GTX 1070 FE / Drivers `nividia-driver 470.x`). Also I am using a fresh Steam installation. But unfortunately, I can't get Proton running correctly.

I always have errors about DirectX (9, 10, 11). The most games will only start on using the `PROTON_USE_WINED3D=1` var, but in some games this seems to be even slower than starting the games directly in Wine. Also I don't remember that I have ever needed this to get the games running on Ubuntu 18.04.

So what I have to do to get Proton on Debian running as on Ubuntu?

Comment: I would suggest asking this on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ubuntu and Debian are still very different animals despite similarities, so it may simply not be possible for your setup to be made to work properly without dev intervention.

Comment: Can you elaborate how you're running Proton? Are you enabling the compatibility layer through Steam settings, or running it independently?

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this problem on MX-Linux, which is Debian based.
If it's still relevant, I solved the problem by doing the following:

1. Running `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
2. Installing Steam `sudo apt install steam`
3. Signing into Steam and going to settings **and enabling the "Enable Steam Play for all other titles" option under Compatibility.**
4. Selecting my desired title, going to Properties, and enabling a compatible version of Proton (usually the latest).

I attempted to launch the title afterward, and it actually launched and was playable!